# How to automatically play unmuted video when changing slides

Tags: html5-video, swiper.js

I have a video slideshow that is created using Swiper JS. Ideally I'd like to make the videos automatically play without muting them when changing slides. I have a play button on top of the video. I don't want users to keep clicking the play button when they change the slides. Is there a way to achieve this without muting the videos? I see the web-based Tiktok site has been doing it. Not sure how they managed to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **(1)** I'm one of those who knows `html5-video` very well, but I don't use SwiperJS. Not obvious why _"changing slides"_ would stop a video playing. Is there any event fired when a slide changes? If yes then maybe you can do something like `if (slide_change_complete == true) { video.play(); }` ... **(2)** Can you not have just one video tag (that plays different `.src` links as a result of changing slides)?

Comment: I've resolved the issue by dynamically updating the src of the video tag when changing the slides